# Set up R in QGIS 3.4 on Mac OS X

Tags: qgis, r, file-path

I'm trying to get R into QGIS on my mac. I've installed the plugin "Processing R Provider plugin" but I can't "get R scripts from online scripts collection". It has something to do with the all caps "PATH" variable or something. The other similar questions like mine asked on here haven't been any helpThe first picture is what my processing toolbox looks like currently. The next two pictures are what I'd like it to look like

[image: asdf]

[image]

[image]